# how does work the func deligate without initializing in c#?

Tags: c#, predicate, func

when I run this code in console application, this code returns "star" but I dont initialize 'index' in 'predicate func'. how does this work? is there a default value?

```
Func<String, int, bool> predicate = (str, index) => str.Length == index;

  String[] words = { "orange", "apple", "Article", "elephant", "star", "and" };
  IEnumerable<String> aWords = words.Where(predicate).Select(str => str);

  foreach (String word in aWords)
     Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Comment: This looks like it would return `star` as that is element 4 in the array (starting at zero)

Comment: Here `index` would be automatically initialized to `0` and incremented with each iteration and hence you get `star` whose length is also the index, 4

Comment: Also the `.Select(str => str)` bit is redundant and not needed at all.

Comment: Your predicate is returning matching elements where the length of the string is the same as it's position in the array. So if you replace `and` with `apple` it will also return that. If your array was `{"", "a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "abcde" }` you would get all values returned.

Comment: It will depend on what position you add the "abcd", if you add it at the 4th index, you will get abcd

Comment: `.Where` has overload with value and index https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__

Comment: @DavidG  yes.thanks:)

Comment: @Slai yes,thanks:)

Answer (score 4):

There are [two overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) of `Enumerable.Where`:

1. One which takes a regular predicate of the form `Func<TSource, Boolean>` and
2. another one, which takes a predicate of the form `Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>` and passes *both the element and its index* to the predicate.

Your code uses the second overload.

Answer (score 3):

The overload of [`.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__) that you called will pass the value *and the index of the current element* to your predicate.

So you get

- "orange", 0
- "apple", 1
- "Article", 2
- "elephant", 3
- "star", 4
- "and", 5

Of those, coincidentally, the length of the word star is the same as it's index in your sequence.

Comment: This doesn't explain why.

Comment: @Enigmativity What do you mean it does not explain why? It's there in the very first sentence. Says the very same thing as the accepted answer. "passes both the element and its index to the predicate" and "will pass the value and the index of the current element" sounds almost identical to me.

Comment: Your answer says _what_ it does, not _why_ it does it. The accepted answer explains that there is an overload and that explains _why_. It then goes on to explain the _what_. Yours only explains the _what_.

Comment: @Enigmativity I assume that people know that if they call a method and the compiler compiles it, it is because that function *exists*. But ok, I have added a link and an explanation.

Comment: The OP is specifically asking "I dont initialize index in my predicate. how this work?" - that means the OP doesn't know. Your answer is excellent now.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to give the number if characters to predicate you can do the following

```
Func<int,Func<string,bool>> predicate = (numOfCharacters) => (str) => str.Length == numOfCharacters;
```

then you can use this like

```
var aWords = words.Where(predicate(5)); //this will get "apple"
```